# MATLAB ODE solver turn extremely close time and plotting shown is too thick

Tags: matlab

I have a ode solver
`[T, Y] = ode23(@(t,y)dydt(t,y),t,y0);` which returns a list of T and a list of Y.
I also try to plot a variable `v` which is a function of `Y` against `T`. In a particular case, `v` is close to 1, for example, 0.999999950378838 but changing with T. 
However, the `T` returns the very close time, for example,

`0.336349531356886
   0.336405066970296
   0.336460602583705
   0.336516138197115
   0.336571661388434
   0.336627184579754
   0.336682707771074
   0.336738230962393
   0.336793745468554
   0.336849259974715
   0.336904774480876
   0.336960288987037
   0.337015784154427
   0.337071279321817
   0.337126774489207
   0.337182269656597
   0.337237743635592
   0.337293217614587
   0.337348691593582
   0.337404165572577
   0.337459629339774
   0.337515093106971
   0.337570556874168
   0.337626020641365
   0.337681473992671
   0.337736927343978
   0.337792380695284
   0.337847834046591
   0.337903265963968`

in unit of `10e-5`. When I plot `v` vs `T`, instead of being a thin line, it is a thick band:
[image].

I suspect because either the unit `10e-5` is too small or ode solver go back and forth in solving. But the output `T` should be all successful steps. How can I deal with this? For example, changing ode options and obtaining a thin line. `v` is not exactly 1. It can be like 0.999999950378838, 0.999999905129327 and 0.999999885006476 and changing with `T`. How can I draw a thin line with this and show the precision also?

Below is three zoomed plot:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice what the `V` axis is. It's all `1.0000` so if you have an `epsilon>=1e-5` then this graph is fine.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff sorry i have edited my question, `v` is not exactly 1. It can be like 0.999999950378838, 0.999999905129327 and 0.999999885006476 and changing with `T`. How can I draw a thin line with this and show the precision also?

Comment: `0.999999905129327` and `0.999999950378838` differ by less than `e-7`. If you are using `single`-word precision, these values are not guaranteed to be distinct by the computer. Are you using `single`-word or `double`-word?

Comment: @Eli Sadoff I have further edited my question. By looking closely in long format, the timestep is not exactly the same but very close. My apologies.

Comment: The response to `single` or `double` precision still has an impact on how to go about this.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff Thank you, I do not know how to check if I use `single` or `double` precision. Is it in ode option or the whole matlab enviroment?

Comment: Call `class(V)` and print out what the result is.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff It is `double`. `T` is also `double`.

Comment: Ok. Try changing the axis parameters, and zooming out and see what happens.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff Thanks. I have added two zoomed in plot. For changing axis parameters is it change them to bigger unit or smaller unit and do I change them in the `plot()`, `set()` or `xlim()`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not a matlab expert I'm much more interested in the mathematical consequences thereof and can help from that stand point.

Comment: @Eli Sadoff Thanks. can you tell me what are mathematical causes of this? Why ode 45 take such small steps? `y` may be stiff but even ode 15s produce thick plot.

Comment: Not possible to say much without runnable code so we can try to replicate this. Have you tried adjusting your tolerances or using another solver like `ode45` or `ode15s`. This looks like stiffness due to an oscillatory ODE function or numerical ringing of some kind.

Comment: @horchler no i have not. I am not familiar with tolerance. Do I adjust to higher tolerance or lower tolerance in both absolute and relative tolerance? Thanks.

Comment: You want [smaller tolerance values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#zmw57dd0e572519). Try adjusting both individually.